# ReactJS in IE11: cannot read property nextSibling of undefined or null

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-11

I have built a ReactJS application that functions fine in all browsers except IE. When I try and access the app on IE11 via VirtualBox, the sign in page loads fine, but the app breaks when you click sign in (upon state change?).

I get the error "cannot read property 'nextSibling' of undefined or null" in relation to this function from the ReactJS code itself:

```
getHostNode: function() {
  var hostNode = this._commentNodes;
  if (hostNode) {
    return hostNode;
  }
  if (!this._closingComment) {
    var openingComment = 
      ReactDOMComponentTree.getNodeFromInstance(this);
    var node = openingComment.nextSibling;
    while (true) {
      ...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? To be clear, the error is thrown on the line **var node = openingComment.nextSibling** in relation to **node** being null.

Thanks.

Comment: Use refs on your selector Node ejm. `var openingComment = this.refs['some-dom-node']`

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  Thanks!

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: So I fixed my problem. Remember this error is the symptom not the problem. My problem was that I was doing an ajax call and promise was not defined for IE. I fixed that problem and this disappeared.